# Classe exibir imagem php

Tags: php, classes, imagem, header

Existe a possibilidade de exibir uma imagem através de métodos de uma classe sem precisar de um arquivo externo para não gerar conflito de header?

Criei uma classe onde a depender chamo uma imagem em uma pasta protegida, gera um imagem com texto ou exibo um qrcode, até ai tudo bem a questão é que precisei criar um arquivo onde apenas instancio a classe e chamo o método e em outro arquivo html chamo esse arquivo apenas com a classe e o método

home.php

```
<img  style="width:100px" src="<?php echo  BASEURL.LIBS; ?>teste/qrcode/token[121212]" >
```

teste.php

```
$imagem = new Teste();
$imagem->exibirQrCode();
```

Comment: Detalhe um pouco melhor o seu problema

Comment: Algo do tipo <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...<!-- base64 data -->' />   ??

Comment: @ViniciusMaia como vc faz hj para exibir imagens se precisar de um classe?

Comment: Não há como o php imprimir uma imagem. Vc pode criar uma classe para chamar o endereço que a imagem está gravada no seu site ou chamar o base64 da sua imagem. E então colocar em uma tag img src="<?php suaclassephp ?>